# Feature Request: Embedding Youtube Videos

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Currently, some StackExchanges allow for Youtube videos to be embedded in either answers or questions. I believe it may be a feature that can be turned on by the top moderators. The only Stacks that I'm aware of that currently have this feature are:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com
https://music.stackexchange.com
https://scifi.stackexchange.com
https://movies.stackexchange.com

Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248250/387725

---

The reason that I'm requesting Youtube videos to be embeddable in answers is that I would like to be able to post videos along with my text based answers. When I write out a 300 word answer, I would like to read my answer in front of a camera for people who would like to enjoy the content through video as well as text.

Longer Youtube videos tend to rank higher than shorter onces which would encourage me to make even more elaborate answers for Webmasters.StackExchange. And the longer the text-based answer posts are, the more likely they are to rank and receive traffic in Google search. Youtube video embeds will also add rich media content that can help boost a post for more organic traffic.

What is my motive for making videos like this? Well, considering that we are all webmasters and programmers here, it would allow for me to start a SEO/Programming Youtube channel that could help lead to career growth. Also, the SEO/Webmaster industry has a high CPC in advertising, so it's a nice vertical for me to want to get into as far as video creation goes.

I hope this is possible! And while we may not be able to embed videos into our answers at this time, would it be alright if I started linking to these videos in my answers as a trial run to see where that goes? If you don't like the videos you can have me remove them afterwards. But I think it's good content! If more of us started making answers with videos perhaps this stackexchange could grow faster.